# HotSwapAgent Popup No Longer Showing

Tags: intellij-idea, hotswapagent

I'm using [HotSwapAgent](https://github.com/HotswapProjects/HotswapAgent) to avoid server restarts with every code change. For the past year this popup is displayed at the bottom of my IntelliJ window whenever I triggered a swap.

However, last night I accidentally committed wrong files to `git`, so I did a `git reset --hard <origin>` today, which fixed the problem but now my HotSwapAgent popup no longer shows up!

It used to be shown here:

[image]

But now there is no indication whether it's succeeded or failed, I have to expand the `Event Log` tab in the bottom-right to see if the swap worked.
[image]

I tried restarting my computer but the problem persists. Why all of a sudden is this occurring? Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you check the [notification settings](https://i.imgur.com/q6EGwS8.png)?

Comment: Ahh, that was it. Not sure why that would've been triggered off? Thank you. I should've definitely checked in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the notification settings for the **Debugger messages** in IntelliJ IDEA:

[image: Debugger messages]

Comment: Do you know why this would've been triggered off seemingly at random? I attributed it to my recent out of character `git` command, but that seems strange.

Comment: `git` should not affect it, it's stored in [CONFIG](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519)`\options\notifications.xml` file.